# How can I optimize a large number of copy and access operations in my numerical solver?

Tags: c++, stl, numerical

I am working on a small pice of code which transports a density from one timestep to another iteratively until the destination time is reachted

The code I am working on has the following form:

1. initialize
2. ping-pong between two buffers now and next

   1. compute new refinement level for next
   2. for each value of the now vector some quantity gets addet to next.

My question: is there a general pattern how to speed up such a piece of code?

Side-question: can I implement this in a nicer/better way using stl algorithms?

---

```
std::vector<double> ping;
std::vector<double> pong;
ping.reserve(1000000);
pong.reserve(1000000);


std::vector* now= &ping;
std::vector* next = &pong;

Initialize(now);  // Fill first timestep
for(size_t t = 0; t < 1000; t++)  // timesteps
{
    size_t M = now->size();
    size_t N = calcNewRefinement(t, now);
    next->resize(N);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) // all elements
    {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < now->size(); j++)
        {
            if (j > 0 && j < N)
                (*next)[i] += ExpensiveFunction((*now)[j-1], (*now)[j], (*now)[j+1], (*next)[i])
            else if (j == 0)
                (*next)[i] += ExpensiveFunction2((*now)[j], (*now)[j+1], (*next)[i])
            else if (j == M-1)
                (*next)[i] += ExpensiveFunction3((*now)[j-1], (*now)[j], (*next)[i])
        }
    }
    vector<double> *intermediate = now;
    now = next;
    next = intermediate;
}
```

Comment: line 3 and 4 are wrong, it should be ping/pong.reserve not -> because they are not pointers to vectors

Comment: Is this your real code? For each `i` `ExpensiveFunction` is called many times and the result assigned to the same `next[i]`.

Comment: Did you profile it? I am sure  `next->resize(N);` is the bottleneck here. You can avoid it by pre allocating the memory

Comment: @Henrik It is a simplified version and yes: every element of the previous timestep contributes to next[i].

Comment: @concept3d shouldn't the reserve in the beginning fix this question

Comment: @Anna yes it should help, but as I said in my comments and in the answer below you should profile.

Comment: It's probably over-simplified. As it stands, your innermost loop is equivalent to `next[i] = ExpensiveFunction3( now[M-2], now[M-1])` or `next[i] = ExpensiveFunction(now[N-2], now[N-1], now[N])` (depends on whether N > M).

Comment: @Henrik Ok, it should be += thanks for spotting the error!

Comment: Still wasteful. What's added to `(*next)[i]` is independent of `i`, so you could pre-calculate it outside the `for i` loop.

Comment: @Henrik Ok, now I feel stupid. It is still oversimplified. I fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general advice for optimizations is to do [profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/375913/509868) first. I assume you already did it, and found that your "copy and access operations" (as described in the question) have to be optimized.

In this case, let me note that the name `ExpensiveFunction` is misleading, because it cannot possibly be expensive when a few copy and access operations are so significant in your code.

The "general pattern" for optimizing is: **look at your inner loop**, and try to remove unnecessary operations.

In your case, you have the following there:

- `for (...; j < now->size(); ...)` - try replacing `now->size()` by `M` - there is a good chance your compiler already did it, but you never know...
- `if (j > 0 && < j < N)` - you can remove these checks completely if you separate your loop into 3 parts (first iteration; middle iterations; last iteration)
- `now[j-1], now[j], now[j+1]` - some c++ implementations insist on array bound checking for each access (this is not required by c++); if yours is like this, try disabling the check, or replace your `std::vector` by `std::array` or (if it doesn't help) by a C-style array
- `next[i] = ...` - as above
- You can try optimizing the code in your expensive functions instead...

Comment: points 2 and 5 should bring most improvements, and 3 if compiler does the check